# How to reset the Password for Scratch Org User (Salesforce DX)?

Tags: salesforcedx

I have created a scratch org from a dev hub org.

I need to reset the password for the newly created scratch org from Salesforce UI and not using command prompt.

When I go to scratch org and try to reset the password for default admin user, it asks me for current password. I do not know the current password of the scratch org. How can I reset the password for scratch org user in order to login from browser.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the CLI? What's the problem with using the prescribed method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to generate the scratch org with the password already in place. Then you wouldn't need to change it.

See [Generate or Change a Password for a Scratch Org User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_passwd.htm)

> By default, new scratch orgs contain 1 administrator user with no password. You can optionally set a password when you create a new user. Use the CLI to generate or change a password for any scratch org user. Once set, you can’t unset a password, you can only change it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

> sfdx force:user:password:generate -u **your**OrgAlias

If you want to check details

> sfdx force:org:display -u **your**OrgAlias